# AR:plotting of points(POI or marker) on iPhone screen

Tags: android, iphone, gis, augmented-reality

problem on calculation of x coordinate for plotting on iPhone screen.When points are within the range of 300 meter we are getting all the point of interest closer even-though In actual they are spread.I have even changed the width of the viewPort from 0.5 to 0.17(In degrees converted 28.647889757 to 10.0).Can anyone suggest such that every points of interest are properly placed with respect to the actual position.

The standard way(Mixare,ARToolkit) of calculating points on AR is

**Calculate using ARKit**

```
double pointAzimuth = coordinate.coordinateAzimuth;

//our x numbers are left based.
double leftAzimuth = self.currentCoordinate.coordinateAzimuth - VIEWPORT_WIDTH_RADIANS / 2.0;

if (leftAzimuth < 0.0) {
    leftAzimuth = 2 * M_PI + leftAzimuth;
}

if (pointAzimuth < leftAzimuth) {
    //it's past the 0 point.
    point.x = ((2 * M_PI - leftAzimuth + pointAzimuth) / VIEWPORT_WIDTH_RADIANS) * 480.0;
} else {
    point.x = ((pointAzimuth - leftAzimuth) / VIEWPORT_WIDTH_RADIANS) * 480.0;
}
```

**IN Mixare:**

```
CGPoint point;
CGRect viewBounds = self.overlayView.bounds;
//NSLog(@"pointForCoordinate:   viewBounds.size.width = %.3f, height = %.3f", viewBounds.size.width, viewBounds.size.height );

double currentAzimuth = self.currentCoordinate.coordinateAzimuth;
double pointAzimuth = coordinate.coordinateAzimuth;


//NSLog(@"pointForCoordinate: location = %@, pointAzimuth = %.3f, pointInclination = %.3f, currentAzimuth = %.3f", coordinate.coordinateTitle, point.x, point.y, radiansToDegrees(pointAzimuth), radiansToDegrees(currentAzimuth), radiansToDegrees(pointInclination) );

double deltaAzimuth = [self deltaAzimuthForCoordinate:coordinate];
BOOL isBetweenNorth = [self isNorthForCoordinate:coordinate];

//NSLog(@"pointForCoordinate: (1) currentAzimuth = %.3f, pointAzimuth = %.3f, isNorth = %d", radiansToDegrees(currentAzimuth), radiansToDegrees(pointAzimuth), isBetweenNorth );

//  NSLog(@"pointForCoordinate: deltaAzimuth = %.3f", radiansToDegrees(deltaAzimuth));
//NSLog(@"pointForCoordinate: (2) currentAzimuth = %.3f, pointAzimuth = %.3f, isNorth = %d", radiansToDegrees(currentAzimuth), radiansToDegrees(pointAzimuth), isBetweenNorth );

if ((pointAzimuth > currentAzimuth && !isBetweenNorth) || 
    (currentAzimuth > degreesToRadians(360-self.viewRange) && 
     pointAzimuth < degreesToRadians(self.viewRange))) {

        // Right side of Azimuth            
        point.x = (viewBounds.size.width / 2) + ((deltaAzimuth / degreesToRadians(1)) * 12);  
    } else {

        // Left side of Azimuth
        point.x = (viewBounds.size.width / 2) - ((deltaAzimuth / degreesToRadians(1)) * 12);    
    }
```